# auto Create database for Birthday alert when someone's bithday is near in vb2010

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2008, vb.net-2010

I want to fill my table(Upcoming Birthdays) from another table(Employee), where there'll be DOB, and the data from the table should be deleted when the DOB is passed.
    My table(Upcoming Birthdays) attributes are as
"Employee_Code" , "Name" , "DOB" , "Days_left_to_Birthday" , "Mobile_Number" , "Email"

Here when "Days_left_to_Birthday" become '0' for any row than that row should auto delete from
the table(Upcoming Birthdays).

I searched for it but couldn't able to find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This examples shows the employees with birthday within 1 month:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Employees 
(
    EmployeesID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    FirstName   NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    LastName    NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    Birthday    DATETIME NOT NULL
);
INSERT  dbo.Employees (FirstName, LastName, Birthday)
VALUES  (N'A', N'X', '19950114'), 
        (N'B', N'Y', '19900915'),
        (N'D', N'Z', '19901016'),       
        (N'E', N'T', '19901117'),
        (N'F', N'V', '19891218');
GO      

CREATE VIEW dbo.vEmployeeWithNextBirthday
AS
SELECT  e.*,
        CASE
            WHEN    e.NextBirthday1 > GETDATE() 
            AND     e.NextBirthday1 <= DATEADD(MONTH, +1, GETDATE()) THEN   e.NextBirthday1
            WHEN    e.NextBirthday2 > GETDATE() 
            AND     e.NextBirthday2 <= DATEADD(MONTH, +1, GETDATE()) THEN   e.NextBirthday2
        END AS NextBirthday
FROM
(       
SELECT  e.EmployeesID, e.FirstName, e.LastName, e.Birthday,
        DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, 0, GETDATE()) - DATEDIFF(YEAR, 0, e.Birthday), e.Birthday) AS NextBirthday1,
        DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, 0, GETDATE()) - DATEDIFF(YEAR, 0, e.Birthday) + 1, e.Birthday) AS NextBirthday2
FROM    dbo.Employees e
) src
GO  

SELECT * FROM dbo.vEmployeeWithNextBirthday;
GO
```

Results:

```
EmployeesID FirstName LastName Birthday   NextBirthday1 NextBirthday2 NextBirthday
----------- --------- -------- ---------- ------------- ------------- -----------------------
1           A         X        1995-01-14 2013-01-14    2014-01-14    NULL
2           B         Y        1990-09-15 2013-09-15    2014-09-15    NULL
3           D         Z        1990-10-16 2013-10-16    2014-10-16    2013-10-16 -- <-- My current date is 2013-09-29
4           E         T        1990-11-17 2013-11-17    2014-11-17    NULL
5           F         V        1989-12-18 2013-12-18    2014-12-18    NULL
```

This query shows those employees with birthday within 1 month:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.vEmployeeWithNextBirthday v
WHERE v.NextBirthday IS NOT NULL;
GO
```

Another test using another current date:

```
DECLARE @CurrentDate DATETIME;
SET     @CurrentDate = '20131215';

SELECT  *,
        CASE
            WHEN    src.NextBirthday1 > @CurrentDate 
            AND     src.NextBirthday1 <= DATEADD(MONTH, +1, @CurrentDate) THEN  src.NextBirthday1
            WHEN    src.NextBirthday2 > @CurrentDate 
            AND     src.NextBirthday2 <= DATEADD(MONTH, +1, @CurrentDate) THEN  src.NextBirthday2
        END AS NextBirthday
FROM
(       
SELECT  *,
        DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, 0, @CurrentDate) - DATEDIFF(YEAR, 0, e.Birthday), e.Birthday) AS NextBirthday1,
        DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, 0, @CurrentDate) - DATEDIFF(YEAR, 0, e.Birthday) + 1, e.Birthday) AS NextBirthday2
FROM    dbo.Employees e
) src
```

Comment: Thanks Bogdan Sahlean.

I'm new to SQL, please explain a bit. I tried it and in return got lots of errors, bcos of my knowledge. :-(

Thanks again bro.

Comment: @Habib: These examples works fine if you have at least SQL Server 2008.

Comment: I'm sure it will.
When I try it gives the following error in creating view.


Msg 166, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
'CREATE/ALTER VIEW' does not allow specifying the database name as a prefix to the object name.

Comment: @Habib: Add the actual statement used to create the view: `CREATE VIEW ...`